# Rails - correct associations for pre-existing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create Rails models for some pre-existing database tables.

There is 1 MainTable, which has 1 ChildTable.

The problem could be the 'foreign keys' are named differently on each table

```
  class MainTable < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :child_tables, :class_name => 'ChildTable', :foreign_key => "child_column_name"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_tables
    self.primary_key = "main_table_column_name"
    self.table_name = 'main_table'
  end


  class ChildTable < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :main_table, :class_name => 'MainTable', foreign_key: "child_column_name", :primary_key => "main_table_column_name"
        self.table_name = 'child_table' 
        self.primary_key = "child_table_column_name"

      end
```

Given that the main table will only every have 1 record per child table, but there could be many child records per main table - do these associations look correct?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
m = MainTable.new
m.some_value = "123"
m.mntbl_key ="999"
c = ChildTable.new
c.something = "Foo"
m.child_tables << c

m.save!
```

EDIT: I am no longer getting an error as I have updated the code above. It works now BUT I have to assign the ids on both tables.
If I assign the id on the Master object, it will **not** automatically give the child object that id in the fk column
i.e.

```
m = MasterTable.new
m.master_table_column_name = 99
c = ChildTable.new
m.child_tables << c
m.save!

-- This will Insert ok into Master but will INSERT a blank row into the child
```

However:

```
m = MasterTable.new
m.master_table_column_name = 99
c = ChildTable.new
c.child_column_name = 99
m.child_tables << c
m.save!

--This works and inserts correctly into both tables
```

--------------------------------- OLD:
But I am getting the error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `ctbl_key'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add migrations files for those tables?

Comment: No the tables preexist and I cannot control anything about them :(

Comment: You don't need a `foreign_key` in the `many` side of a `has_many` relationship.

Comment: @user3437721 Yep of course. But what I've meant was not migrations but `schema.rb` file. Sorry brain fart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-to-many association only uses one foreign key column - not two.

Typically in rails its setup as so:

```
class Parent 
  has_many :children
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

The actual association is stored in the `children.parent_id` column.

So lets say we have an non-conventional foreign key:

```
class Parent 
  has_many :children, foreign_key: 'padre_id'
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: 'padre_id'
end
```

Easy enough. We just have to tell the associations on both side what the foreign key is. Note that the `class_name` option is not needed as long as the class name can be deduced from the name of the association.

Custom primary keys or table names are not a problem either as ActiveRecord looks at the model class definitions when resolving associations.

```
class Parent 
  self.primary_key = :custom_pk
  has_many :children, foreign_key: 'padre_id'
end

class Child
  self.table_name = 'bar'
  # this will correctly reference parents.foo
  belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: 'padre_id'
end
```

There is also the universal issue that you must save a record before you can add children to it:

```
irb(main):024:0> m = MainTable.new
=> #<MainTable custom_pk: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):025:0> m.child_tables.new
=> #<ChildTable id: nil, padre_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):026:0> m.save!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Child tables is invalid
    from (irb):26
```

Starting in Rails 5 `belongs_to` associations are non-optional by default. So the `child_tables` instance is not valid since the `padre_id` is nil.

You either need to save the parent record first:

```
irb(main):033:0> m = MainTable.create!
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  MainTable Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "main_table" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "custom_pk"  [["created_at", "2018-11-20 17:31:09.545476"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-20 17:31:09.545476"]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
=> #<MainTable custom_pk: 5, created_at: "2018-11-20 17:31:09", updated_at: "2018-11-20 17:31:09">
irb(main):034:0> m.child_tables.new
=> #<ChildTable id: nil, padre_id: 5, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):035:0> m.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  MainTable Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "main_table".* FROM "main_table" WHERE "main_table"."custom_pk" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["custom_pk", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ChildTable Create (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "child_table" ("padre_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["padre_id", 5], ["created_at", "2018-11-20 17:31:21.737989"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-20 17:31:21.737989"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):036:0>
```

Or build from the belongs_to association on the other side:

```
irb(main):027:0> c = ChildTable.new
=> #<ChildTable id: nil, padre_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):028:0> c.build_main_table
=> #<MainTable custom_pk: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):029:0> c.save!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  MainTable Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "main_table" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "custom_pk"  [["created_at", "2018-11-20 17:24:29.344332"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-20 17:24:29.344332"]]
  ChildTable Create (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "child_table" ("padre_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["padre_id", 3], ["created_at", "2018-11-20 17:24:29.346764"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-20 17:24:29.346764"]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Comment: but my foreign keys are named different on each table, I'm not sure what your saying here?

Comment: Are you saying it can't be done with a foreign key called something different in each table?

Comment: No, I'm saying that a one to many association is built with only one foreign key (which is on the `belongs_to` side). The foreign key references the primary key on the other table. Since its one column on one table it cannot have different names on each side. This is really basic relational database design stuff and applies everywhere. Not just rails.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out and update tomorrow, appreciate the response.

Comment: Could you maybe update the answer so it is clear which column I should reference as the foreign key, in your example you use 'padre_id' which I assume is the parent column?  Remember it is not the primary key of the parent table which is stored in the child table.

Comment: If the column referenced by the foreign key is not the primary key then you need to setup the association as `belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: 'the_fk_column_on_child', primary_key: 'some_other_key'`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: Thanks and the parent association - does it need a foreign key reference? If you look at my original post I thought I did this but maybe I got the keys round the wrong way..

Comment: No - you're just confusing things. The referenced column on parent is not a foreign key. Its just a column thats referenced, just like the id is not a foreign key. It might be a foreign key pointing to a third table but thats irrelevant for this association.

Comment: I sure am confused! So if the child looks like : belongs_to :parent, foreign_key: 'the_fk_column_on_child', primary_key: 'some_other_key'. How should the parent look?

Comment: `has_many :children, foreign_key: 'the_fk_column_on_child'` - the foreign_key option always points to the `belongs_to` side.

Comment: It turns out that you have to specify the custom "primary key" on the `has_many` side as well `has_many :child_tables, foreign_key: :the_fk_column_on_child, primary_key: :some_other_key`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to what I am using now, but I am still getting the same error, what primary key should I add on the has_many side? The Main Table or Child Table?

Comment: Ok I have managed to get it working (mostly) and see my updated question edit.  Basically now the save of main table and child table works if you assign the id to both objects

Comment: `has_many :child_tables, class_name: 'ChildTable', foreign_key: "child_column_name", primary_key: "main_table_column_name"`

Comment: If you have an association between where A has many Bs the foreign key is always on B and the primary key is on A. Don't know how to explain this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the issue you're facing, but at the moment you're initializing new MainTables and ChildTables, however you're not saving them.

This means they won't be assigned an ID, which in turn means when you try and assign a Child Table to the Main Table, it doesn't have an ID for the main table (or itself) to create a join record with.

Try saving the records before shovelling in child records

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to assign a child record before the parent record is saved - it will try to create a join record which requires both the parent ID and child ID. I'm pretty sure the minimum is that the parent record is saved first

Comment: If you really want to go down that route I think you'll need to look at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html, specifically 'accepts_nested_attributes_for', which allows you to create a parent and child record in one transaction

Comment: In your case this would let you do: 
MainTable.create(title: 'bla', child_table_attributes: { title: 'bla2' } )
Which will create a Main Table, with a child table related to it